# Why is Google showing the same Stack Overflow Q&A post twice with different dates?

Tags: discussion, bug, google

When searching for "visual studio warning notimplementedexception" I see the same Q&A listed twice in Google, with the same *green text* for the URI - but with different dates, different page titles (note the "C# - " prefix), and title widths, so at first-glance the results seem distinct.

Is this a bug in Google (lol), or a bug in how Stack Overflow is attaching date metadata to pages to Google, or an issue with microformats, or something else?

[image: Google.com search result screenshot]

Comment: Question and Answers are indexed by Google.

Comment: @rene Clicking either of the results took me to the Question, not to an Answer.

Comment: [Cross-site dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297654/332043)

Comment: It shows the last edit date, not the creation date.  Probably a hack on the SO end to make content look "fresh".  How Google started collecting all SO hits in a single entry and ordering them in reverse is a tragedy, but the kind of thing that happens when web sites lie.  At least they don't do it for every post.